# spring-boot own and remote OAuth2 authorization server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I have a spring boot application and i would like to combine my own and remote OAuth2 authorization server (Google, Facebook...) plus BASIC authentication.

i would like to have:

1. Regular login/password flow (with email confirmation) to access any url except /api
2. OAuth2 to access /api urls
3. SSO (Google, Facebook...)

I have an issue with SSO. I want it works like this:
when user successfully authorized i would get email address then if it does not already exist  in my app i will register one (send login/password to email) then grant for user new token from my own OAuth2 authorization server and send that token back instead of token that user got from remote server.

I have made a examle app:
https://github.com/LifeIsGoodMF/oauth2-workflow

take a look at AuthenticationSuccessHandler in

https://github.com/LifeIsGoodMF/oauth2-workflow/blob/master/src/main/java/com/test/conf/OAuth2AuthClientConfig.java

Can anyone help to figure out how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a good spring boot reference implementation [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/samples/oauth2)